# Convert string to datetime in Azure automation Account (powershell)

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to get the difference in days between a string datetime and the current date. I tried following code on my local PC

```
$Dateinname = "24-05-2022"
$Retention = (New-TimeSpan -Start $DateInName -End (get-date)).Days

        if ($Retention -gt 14){
           //do something
         }
```

However in Automation Account 'Powershell script', the same code provides following error:

```
New-TimeSpan : Cannot bind parameter 'Start'. Cannot convert value "[datetime]::parseexact" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." At line:72 char:43 + ... $Retention = (New-TimeSpan -Start [datetime]::parseexact($DateIn ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-TimeSpan], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewTimeSpanCommand
```

I changed the start conversion multiple times with

1. [datetime]DateInName
2. [datetime]::parseexact($DateInName, 'dd-MMM-yyyy', $null)
3. changed the '-' into '/'.

But still the automation account fails.
Is there something I missed when creating the runbook like inscript, is there a model I forgot to install ?

Comment: If the date format in `$Dateiname` in `"24-05-2022"`, then the format obviously is `'dd-MM-yyyy'` (2-digit Day, 2-digit Month, 4digit Year). Do `$DateInName = [datetime]::ParseExact('24-05-2022', 'dd-MM-yyyy', $null)`. If you want to perform this conversion inside the `New-TimeSpan` call, wrap it in brackets `(..)`

Comment: thanks, totally not saw that the format inside the conversion needs to be the same as the variable. If you can paste this in an answer i will accept is as a solution.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I should have posted as answer straight away, otherwise this will remain an 'unanswered' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here my comment as answer

The date format in `$DateInName` shows it is formatted as `'dd-MM-yyyy'`
(2-digit Day, 2-digit Month, 4digit Year).

Either do

```
$DateInName = [datetime]::ParseExact('24-05-2022', 'dd-MM-yyyy', $null)
$Retention = (New-TimeSpan -Start $DateInName -End (get-date)).Days
```

Or, if you want to perform this conversion inside the New-TimeSpan call, wrap it in brackets `(..)`:

```
$DateInName = '24-05-2022'
$Retention = (New-TimeSpan -Start ([datetime]::ParseExact($DateInName, 'dd-MM-yyyy', $null)) -End (Get-Date)).Days
```